# Validate proxied connections with the .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, proxy, proxies

I'm struggling with the following issue.

My goal is to deny all connections to my site except for a couple of IPs. This is what I have in my .htaccess file.

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from **.***.**.*** #person1
allow from **.***.**.*** #person2

# For Redirection
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ site/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

This was working just fine until I installed SSL with CloudFlare. The client IPs are now showing with a comma.

g.e. The hosting access logs and $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] show as `12.123.12.123,` (see the comma at the end).

So since then, the `.htaccess` file is not validating correctly.

Does anybody know how to validate this situations? I'm not so familiar with Apache.

Thanks in advance!

**What I have tried and don't work**

```
allow from **.***.**.***/1

allow from **.***.**.***,
```

**SOLUTION**

Yey! Found the solution faster than expected. This is what worked for me.

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
SetEnvIF X-Forwarded-For "**.***.***.***" AllowIP  #person1
SetEnvIF X-Forwarded-For "**.***.***.***" AllowIP  #person2
Allow from env=AllowIP
```